# How to include package_data in pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-wheel, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to build a Flask + React application where the React client is built, moved into the python directory, and packaged as static files within a wheel build from the Flask package with `pip wheel . --no-deps`.

The file structure looks like this:

```
* client/
* server/
  * my_project/
    * build/ -> static files generated by building the client
    * app.py
    * ... -> additional python files
  * pyproject.toml
```

I was able to get this working with setup.py by generating a list of client files by parsing the build/ directory and creating a list of all filenames and adding the following to the `setuptools.setup()` call:

```
package_data={"my_project": client_files},
```

After moving to pyproject.toml, I can only get it to package:

just the python files:

```
...

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["my_project"]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
build = ["*.*"]
```

or

just the client files:

```
...

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["my_project"]
```

I also can't get the behavior to change at all using a MANIFEST.in file.

Comment: You will improve your chances of getting useful help if you provide a clean, full, standalone [mre].